# How to access values from dynaaction form in jsp

Tags: struts

I can set the attributes in the servlet and I can get those values in jsp by accessing the get attribute. 
do we have anything to access values in jsp like that.

For Example:

```
DynaActionForm home = (DynaActionForm) form;
String age = (String)home.get("age");
```

I want to access this **age** in jsp.

Please help me solve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your struts-config.xml file is configured correctly, all you need to do is use the [bean:write tag](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-bean.html#write).

Answer (score 1):

You can add the map of your formbean in the request scope like that:

```
        Map m = dynaform.getMap();
    request.setAttribute("mapForm", m);
```

And then access propertys into your jsp with:

```
${mapForm['nameOfYourFormProperty'] }
```

This is using JSTL. Otherwise you can use that:

```
<%= ((Map)request.getAttribute("mapForm")).get("nameOfYourFormProperty") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if you can access DynaActionForm values directly within the Struts View (jsp) component?

You could try setting the DynaActionForm as a request attribute in your Struts Action:

```
DynaActionForm myForm = (DynaActionForm) form;
request.setAttribute("myForm", myForm);
```

Then in your JSP page import DynaActionForm and do something like:

```
DynaActionForm myForm = (DynaActionForm) request.getAttribute("myForm");
String age = (String) myForm.get("var");
```

But it would be much better to just access the value you needed within the Struts Action and just set that value onto the request or session.